# SQL server erro: servidor local está inacessível

Tags: sql-server

Quando tento usar o SQL server management studio 2008 recebo esse erro:

> servidor local está inacessível

Comment: Você startou o serviço do seu servidor local?

Comment: Como eu faço isso amigo?

Answer (score 0):

Start o serviço do SQL, va em Menu Iniciar --> digite serviços (ou services), vai abrir uma lista de serviços do windows, procure o serviço do SQL SERVER e start ele.

Abaixo uma imagem de exemplo, não é esse o serviço do sql é só um exemplo, mas o processo é o mesmo.

Encontre o serviço (estara escrito sql server nele), clique nele e do lado esquerdo clique em Start.

[image: serviços do windows]

Comment: Paulo Roberto, não há nada relacionado a SQL na lista de serviços, já revirei ela umas 5 vzs e não achei nada. Será que reinstalar ele resolve ? Se sim, como faço pq n achei  nenhum Desinstalador dele, só varias coisas dele no remover programas do painel de controle mas não uma única opção.

Comment: Após uma pesquisa aqui descobri que faltava o SQL express mas agr q tenho ele e o management studio tbm aparece servidor inacessível. Eu já verifiquei o serviço do SQL server express e esta ativado, mas ele continua dizendo que esta inacessível qnd tento me conectar.